# Android ActivityNotFoundException Intent

Tags: android, exception, google-play

I'm noticing a few errors flagged by analytics:

```
class android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
Msg: android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult:1408 (No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.example.myprog })
```

The below code is to get a Android Market to open. Am I correct in thinking that this error means that Android Market is not installed and there is no other app registered to handle market URLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It seems that market application is missing. It can happen if you check the app on emulator.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is I only offer my App through the marketplace, so people must be getting versions from elsewhere and sideloading them but not with market. :/

Comment: You can prevent that with licensing. http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/adding-licensing.html